# Failed to set TLS communication when operate chaincode(query, invoke) from application to peer node(endorser) in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, grpc

As I mentioned in the title, I have a question about setting TLS communication from application to peer node in Hyperledger Fabric.

To configure this network, I utilize fabric tutorials :

1) Building Your First Network

2) Writing Your First Application

(both are shown in online hyperledger docs)

The key is that fabric tutorial 1 executes chaincode in internal CLI on TLS enabled mode, and fabric tutorial 2 executes chaincode out of CLI, using nodejs script file, on TLS disabled mode. So I inspected these tutorials and collaborated with them.

The goal is to configure blockchain network on TLS mode and communicate applications out of network. Here is my blockchain network topology using hyperledger fabric 1.1.0 alpha.

[image]

I built blockchain network(TLS ON) in practical and components are shown in the figure above. As you see now, Application is failed to communicate to peer0.org1 node on TLS.

At first, I built blockchain network without TLS option and when I execute chaincode from application, It works well. (success to query all data, invoke new data, and check adding new blocks in Orderer logs)

So I deleted that network and reconfigure network On TLS enabled mode.
Network configuration works well and admin enrollment & user register is completed.

[image]

I executed query chaincode on application to peer0 On TLS enabled network, but It failed.

[image]

That error is about status code error. As far as I know, gRPC works on TLS, so this error message is about TLS communication setup.

To setting up TLS mode, I have tried all these attempts that I know. But I didn’t solve it and I don’t know what is the reason.

What should I do? I would appreciate if you give advice to fix this TLS problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like an instance of [this issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/130) with gRPC. Starting with gRPC 1.8.4, those errors should be reported with the status code UNKNOWN, which is a signal that the library using gRPC can retry that request.

Comment: I was late to check your comment, so sorry. I solved that problem using word 'grpcs'(not using the word 'grpc') because It is TLS communication so I should add 's' to word 'grpc'. And I should add TLS certificate to peer instance(in application). Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @DuDu what is the TLS certificate you added here. Very little is explained about the PEM file to be used in the documentation.